# What is オーション and why is it called that?

Tags: meaning, words, etymology

A recipe for home-made ramen calls for オーション. I am having a hard time figuring out what that is exactly, having checked dictionaries and Google Translate to no avail.

I did find several online shopping sites that sell オーション. Just to list a few:

https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%97%A5%E6%B8%85%E8%A3%BD%E7%B2%89-%E5%BC%B7%E5%8A%9B%E7%B2%89-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3-25kg/dp/B005SQ0OZW

https://tomiz.com/item/00000603

From their descriptions it seems オーション is just bread flour? Why is it called オーション?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes オーション is just one of the product names for flour sold by Nisshin.

Information is limited because it's not officially for retail. [This site](https://www.e-sousyoku.com/) seems to have lots of official information about professional-use flours sold by Nisshin, but unfortunately only experts and restaurant owners are allowed to access. Still, judging from [this search result](https://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/search/%E6%97%A5%E6%B8%85%E8%A3%BD%E7%B2%89%20%E5%B0%8F%E9%BA%A6%E7%B2%89%20%E6%A5%AD%E5%8B%99%E7%94%A8/0/), I think it's safe to assume オーション is named after *ocean* (or maybe its French equivalent *océan*).

Comment: It would probably be written オセアン if it came from French, or at least that's how I pronounce it, and I can't really think of another transliteration

Comment: @Rightleg [These](https://ja.forvo.com/word/oc%C3%A9an/) sound like ウシヨ or ウーシヨン to my ears. (I know almost nothing about French, though)